# Nested Loop Time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
for ( i =  0;  i <= n; i = i +2 )
     for ( j = n; j >=  i;  j - - )
```

I know the outer loop runs for n/2 + 1 times

i cant figure out how many times would the inner loop runs

```
if we assume n = 10 

the inner loop runs for 10 times when i = 0 
the inner loop runs for 8 times when i = 2
and so on but i cant figure out what time complexity would that be?
```

Comment: It may help to know that `1 + 2 + … + n = n * (n + 1) / 2`. See [Triangular numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like average number of iterations within inner loop is `n/2`. Then:

```
(n/2 +1) * n/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume an arbitrary `n` and consider an `i` such that `0 <= i <= n`.
You're right in saying that the outer loop will run for `n/2+1` times.

Let's see how many times the inner loop will run for a given `n` and `i`. The inner loop's j values go from i to n like this

```
 i, i+1, i+2, i+3, ..., n   
 |______________________|
            |
        n-i+1 terms
```

So basically the number of steps the inner loops takes is the number of terms in this sequence which if you look is `n-i+1` (you actually have an error in your question; if `n = 10` and `i = 0`, the inner loop takes 11 steps not 10).

So to get the total number of steps the two loops make, we need to `sum n-i+1 for i=0 to i<=n, i+=2`. Let `S(n-i+1)` denote this sum. Then:

```
 S(n-i+1)
 = S(n+1) - S(i)
 = (n+1)*S(1) - S(i)    # since n+1 is a constant we can pull it out
 = (n+1)*(n/2 + 1) - S(i)    # S(1) is just equal to the number of steps of the outer loop which is n/2+1
 = (n+1)*(n/2 + 1) - (0 + 2 + 4 + ... + n)
```

Now `S(i) = 0 + 2 + 4 + ... + n` which is an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). The sum of this is `n*(n/4+1/2)` thus our total sum is

```
 = (n+1)*(n/2 + 1) - n*(n/4+1/2)
 = n^2/2 + n + n/2 + 1 - n^2/4 -n/2
 = n^2/4 + n + 1
```

And so the dominant term is the `n^2` resulting in a complexity of `O(n^2)`.