# Big O Notation of Java Nested Loops

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, big-o, nested-loops

I am aware of the various rates of Big O such as O(n^2) and O(n), and have no problem determining the Big O value of simple nested for loops such as the following.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
   //Simple Statement
```

The following loop is clearly O(n^2), but how does one go about solving for Big O when the inner nested loop is dependent on the outer loop.
 Example

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = n - 1; j >= i; j--)
    //Simple Statement
```

would T(n) simply be n*(n-1-i) ?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32446002/577108 ?

Comment: Just add up all the inner iterations: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html (as commented in the other question as well)

Answer (score 3):

It is still on the order of n^2.  You only care about the most significant term.  The second expression would look something line O(n^2 - an) where a is some sort of coefficient.  All you really care about is the n^2.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop runs n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 times.  This is a Gaussian sum and equals n * (n + 1) / 2, or (n^2 + n) / 2, hence O(n^2).

Comment: I reviewed my algorithm and tried to find the sum, but am unsure why the outer loop was not multiplied in your answer. Why isn't it  n *  [(n)(n-1)]/2? The outer loop runs n times, and the inner loop is a Gaussian sum with a leading term of n-1 and a final term of 1. So [(n-1)*(n-1 + 1], which would imply n(n-1)(n)

Comment: Each term in the sum represents the number of iterations of the inner loop in one iteration of the outer loop.  So the sum accounts for all executions of the inner loop.

Comment: Wouldn't that make this algorithm O(n^3) then? I'm just unsure why the outer loop is not multiplied by the inner.

Comment: After further reviewing Big O now finally makes sense to me. In a sense, O(n) relates to the pattern used to express the simple statements. There was no need for me to multiply the sum by n, because the sum represents the total number of simple statement iterations.